# I got an error in train_score can anyone solve?

Tags: python

I got an error in Train_score but not in test_score how can i solve this:

```
MLA_compare.loc[row_index, 'MLA Time'] = cv_results['fit_time'].mean()
MLA_compare.loc[row_index, 'MLA Train Accuracy Mean'] = cv_results['train_score'].mean()
MLA_compare.loc[row_index, 'MLA Test Accuracy Mean'] = cv_results['test_score'].mean()
```

**KeyError: 'train_score'**

Answer (score 2):

You must add the conditional to the line

```py
cv_results = model_selection.cross_validate( alg, data1[data1_x_bin],
                     data1[Target], cv=cv_split, return_train_score=True )
```